# Hybris Synchronization calling prepareInterceptor

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I wrote a ProductPrepareInterceptor to always run a logic before save product to set a property called "sellable" to true or false depending on it's other properties value.

But when i run the Synchronization of just one product, it calls my interceptor 36 times, always with the same properties in the object.

So my question is: Is this behavior normal? Why the synchronization call the save() function to the same object so many times?

Comment: Did you try running a printStackTrace on each run to see if it give any tips? How are your categories configured? Are you using classification categories?

Comment: I've figured it out that it's calling the interceptor for each property that it's synchronizing, ctx.getDirtyAttributes(model) returns just one of the attributes each time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's normal but I can say that you use an interceptor while you should use dynamic attribute.

When you wan't to have a value calculated depending on the value of other values, then use dynamic attribute.

For exemple in you items definition

```
            <attribute qualifier="myDynamicAttribute" type="java.lang.String">
                <description>my dynamic attribute</description>
                <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" optional="true" />
                <persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="myDynamicAttributeBean" />
            </attribute>
```

And in your spring your define the handler:

```
<bean id="myDynamicAttributeBean" class="com.foo.MyDynamicAttributeHandler"/>
```

Then the class looks like :

```
public class MyDynamicAttributeHandlerimplements DynamicAttributeHandler<String, ProductModel>
{
    @Override
    public String get(final ProductModel model)
    {
         //your logic here to calculate the value
    }

    @Override
    public void set(final ProductModel model, final String value)
    {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

If you need a localized version extends `DynamicLocalizedAttributeHandler` you'll then have to implement two other methods `public String get(final ProductModel model, final Locale locale)` and `public void set(final ProductModel model, final String value, final Locale locale)`.

Note that `set` methods must return `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it's value depends on other objects values as well, and we are currently adding more rules to the interceptor, probably we will add more rules in the future. Our synchronization proccess already takes a lot of time to sync all the catalog. If we were able to prevent the interceptor being called so many times we would reduce this time considerably.